# file_put_contents and $_SERVER data

Tags: php, file-put-contents

```
$file = 'userdata.txt';
file_put_contents($file, print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 
FILE_APPEND);
```

In userdata.txt I have: `1` (don't know why)

Finally, I want to save to `.txt`  `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) And [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $file = 'userdata.txt';
> file_put_contents($file, print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), FILE_APPEND);
> ```

The [`print_r` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) (in the case above) prints the output to `stdout` and returns `TRUE` to the caller. So what you have is identical to:

```
$file = 'userdata.txt';
print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
file_put_contents($file, TRUE, FILE_APPEND);
```

The `TRUE` then becomes `1` when it is [converted to `string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting).

The easiest way to do what you want is to simply skip the `print_r` call:

```
$file = 'userdata.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], FILE_APPEND);
```

Or if you want the specific formatting produced by `print_r`, you can add a second parameter:

```
$file = 'userdata.txt';
file_put_contents($file, print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], TRUE), FILE_APPEND);
```

This will cause `print_r` to return the output rather than print it directly.